# QuerySet.union() django 1.11.4

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django 1.11 introduced cool feature to combine querysets.

You can make something like:
`combined_qs = qs1.union(qs2, qs3)`

And voila! `combined_qs` has all querysets together keeping their order (btw, am I right here?). I need this, as qs1 should be the first, qs2 the second and so on.

But the challenging part is those querysets can't be ordered by any field. As I get it, it happens due MySql ignores any ORDER BY statements in UNION, and it can be done only via subquery. And I don't get it how it can be done via Django ORM without too much raw SQL magic.

Any ideas on how those querysets can be unioned with respect to their order_by() statements?

**Upd.**
Seems like I saw what I wanted to see and not what it is. Perhaps, I still should stay with django-querysetsequence. Which is a good lib, but I had a hope we have finally got the native method.

Comment: With `print combined_qs.query` you can print out the resulting SQL and have a look.

Comment: Hmm, have a look at what?

Comment: It can't. You can convert them to a list of objects and combine the lists.

Comment: Sachin Kukreja, unfortunately, converting them to lists will evaluate the querysets at the moment. That's no good.